# do closures in c# cause code bloat?

Tags: c#, clr

Do closures in c# cause code bloat in the generated il? I was told to avoid lambdas with closure variables as they generate hidden classes in the object file that can store the context for the lambda. A class for every lambda with the closed over variables. Is this true? Or does the compiler reuse an existing class, like Tuple or some internal class?

Comment: So what if it does? How do you imagine that affects you? The question only really makes sense with some idea of what the tradeoffs are.

Comment: What about iterator blocks? The yield keyword? Auto-implemented properties? `using` statements? They all produce generated code - would you call them all bloat?

Comment: Yes they are fat compared to a simple method call.  No code reuse.  But no matter, consuming a half a gigabyte of virtual memory for data requires no effort.  Half a gig of *code* takes an enormous amount of effort.  You are almost surely optimizing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Extra classes are only generated when they need to be - when you capture variables other than `this`. However, this isn't really code bloat in most cases - it's *necessary* in order to make the delegate work the way you need it to.

In *some* cases you could write more efficient code yourself, but usually to get a delegate with the same effect, you'd end up writing code which was similar to what the compiler would generate for you... but considerably harder to read.

Most of the time you shouldn't worry about this sort of "bloat" - avoid micro-optimizing for performance to start with - optimize for readability, and *measure* the performance instead of guessing about it. Then you can attack the bits of code which *really* matter, and maybe sacrifice a bit of readability for performance there, when you've proved that it's worth it.

(Writing modern C# and deliberately avoiding lambda expressions is like trying to code with one hand tied behind your back. If the person advising you is worried about the "bloat" of closures, you could probably give him a heart attack by showing him the state machine generated for async/await in C# 5...)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why closing over this does not cause a class to be generated? Also, if you have multiple lambdas in the same method which close over the same variables, does the compiler share a single generated class that's shared between each lambda?

Comment: Also, this question is for a mature codebase with 100s of thousands of lines of code, and needs to run smoothly on 5-6 year old machines.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is true.

A class that keeps track of the variable needs to exist. A `Tuple` or internal class would not be able to do this for all possible code paths, so such a state machine needs to be generated in IL specifically for each lambda/closure.

Whether this is a problem for your application or not is something for you to determine.

Comment: No, it's not really a state machine for a lambda expression. It's just a class with the current state of the captured variables, and a method for the delegate. An *iterator block* generates a true state machine.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for making the distinction. Answer amended.

Comment: For locals and instance variables a new class is not created. See http://blog.sandeeprawat.com/2012/05/lambda-closure-and-compiler-generated.html